# #each statement on HTML showing only last item

Tags: arrays, frontend, azure-cosmosdb, each, sveltekit

I need to print in my list all the items of my array, but I'm getting only the last item printed. When I console.log it, I can see all the items. Not sure why this is happening, I tried to figure out using all I've got, but none worked.

```js
let examples = [];

onMount(async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
        "https://<my-api>/db/v1/cosmos/{container}",
        {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "<api-key>":
                    "<my-api-key>",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                query: "SELECT * FROM c ORDER BY c.name ASC",
            }),
        }
    ).then((response) => response.json());

    for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        console.log(response.data[i].name);
        examples = response.data[i].name;
    }
});
```

On my HTML I'm using the following loop:

```html
{#each examples as example}
    <ListgroupItem class="text-base font-semibold gap-2">
        Name: {examples} <br />
    </ListgroupItem>
{/each}
```

What I'm getting in return, is just only the last item of my array. If I use example instead of examples, on my foreach loop, my return is only the letters.

[image]

When I'm using SvelteKit and Cosmos DB.
Something I don't get is that if the item has 5 letters, it will print 5 rows. If another item has 7 letters, it will print 7 rows. Not sure why. I am not getting any error.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
I also have tried using those below, but they didn't work.

```js
examples.unshift(0);
examples.push(examples);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are always assigning to what is supposed to be a list, the name of the current item, so at the end you are left with just the name of the last item:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
    console.log(response.data[i].name);
    examples = response.data[i].name;
}
```

If you only want a list of name this should be replaced with:

```js
examples = response.data.map(x => x.name)
```

The `#each` is also wrong, it iterates the variable but you are not using the item, but the list variable, it should be:

```html
{#each examples as example}
    <ListgroupItem class="text-base font-semibold gap-2">
        Name: {example} <br /> <!-- example, not examples -->
    </ListgroupItem>
{/each}
```

(As `examples` was just a string before, it iterated the letters in the string.)